# Center divs etc. horizontally with CSS

Tags: html, css

How do you center a div or anything else horizontally, so that on both sides the empty spaces are equal? And the div is exactly in the middle? No matter the size of the objects.

Take for example: the Stackoverflow site itself. 
Except for the black header on the top of this site, everything is in the middle and the empty spaces on both sides are equal to each other.

I've searched for a long time, but I only encountered the wrong answers or vague answers.

Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. here is [why](http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html)

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

In css, you can use `margin: auto;`

A common pattern is to wrap your content in a container with a fixed width and add `margin: auto;` to it.

Answer (score 0):

The common way is using `margin:0px auto`. Look at the following example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
     This is my content Div.
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test
{    
 width:60%;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 margin:0px auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLjp4/1/)